# How can I import open street map power grid data into QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I wanted to download power grid network of Cologne city from following url
http://www.flosm.de/en/Power-Grid.html

But I could only download in jpg format. I wanted to import this in GIS as vector (*.shp) or raster image but failed to do so.

Comment: Links to SVG download are inactive, the link for vector download via partner website is broken. I suggest you download an excerpt of OSM data directly, and filter the ways by the relevant way tags or relation tags. There are plugins for QGIS you may use, or you take the long way using Osmosis or Osm2pgsql.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Quick OSM plug-in to download the data you need. It's very simple to use. Set the screen to show the extents of your project, set the project CRS and enable on-the-fly reprojection. Then start the plug-in (Web -> Quick OSM) select the required key ('power' in your case) and press 'Run query'. See the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But when i try to install "QuickOSM" in QGIS through plugin manager, I get the following error message "The plugin is broken, Python said: cannot import name dataobjects". I found out that there is a bug for 64 bit version of QuickOSM plugin. Do you have any idea or suggestions for me? Thank you once again.

Comment: Sorry to hear this. The plug-in works well for me in QGIS 2.9 under Ubuntu 14.04. I think it would be worth reporting the bug on the plug-in's issues page at Git: https://github.com/3liz/QgisQuickOSMPlugin/issues

Comment: I was able to run "QuickOSM" by updating QGIS to its latest version. But, how did you get the power grid "project"? Thats what I wanted to import in QGIS. I wanted Power Grid network of COlogne City, Germany. Its only available through http://www.flosm.de/en/Power-Grid.html but only can download jpeg file. Thank you for help so far.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood the question and thought you were trying to extract the data you need from the OSM data set. You have a problem, if you can't get at the original vector data I think all you can do is download the JPG, georeference it and then trace the power network. N.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the data from the original Openstreetmap database. While openstreetmap.org offers such export (without filtering), flosm.de only allows to download their rendered images.

To get and filter OSM data, download extracts for the part of your world from Geofabrik, then filter the data with osmosis or osmfilter.

You can find sample osmosis filter rules here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Ajoessen/Osmosis (in German).

You can add the filtered data into QGIS with `Add vector layer`, or the Openstreetmap plugin step 2 and 3 (you did the download of step 1 already).